# How to add tab layout to a fragment in navigation bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have created a navigation drawer and added fragments to it.Now I want to insert tab layout into one of the fragment.I have added tab layout into one fragment containing 2 tabs,but I dont know how to add contents into each of these tabs separately.Please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjY3f.png)
I need my tabs to look like in the image..Each tab having its own fragment

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to add contents into each of these tabs separately

**Answer** : Same as you add TabLayout in activity.

fragment_parent.xml is parent fragment having `TabLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".NewFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:tabTextColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

FragmentParent.java

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("A"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("B"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("C"));
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
              return new FragmentChild();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentChild();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentChild();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
}
```

fragment_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentChild.java

```
public class FragmentChild extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);


}
```

Comment: RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new AdapterOne(); In this line AdapterOne() is showing error

Comment: This is a dummy layout and code inside fragment child, you can change its layout and java class of child fragment according to your need

Comment: I edited my answer to blank fragment child, make it yours with your stuff

Comment: I need fixed tabs..But here it is swiping tab..On displaying it shows only the current tab in app bar layout..I need all tab to be displayed.

Comment: Can you post an image of your requirement in your question?

Comment: image is added..Pls help